# Best method to recognize objects?

Tags: c++, classification, image-recognition, traffic

I am trying to recognize traffic signs, I already detect them, but  now I have to do something to know which one is each of them, I have been reading about the cascade classifier http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html but i would need 1 for each sign right? Furthermore i am having some issues with the merging of vec files. What do you recommend me to use for this object recognition?  i am not sure if the cascade classifer is the best method.....

Thanks a lot fot your help!!

I also posted it here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/65836/best-method-to-recognize-objects/

Comment: yea. it would work. after training the three classifiers you can take the highest score and output that, making a multiclass classifier. As for the vec files you should use the function provided, don't think there's a reason to merge.

Comment: but with the function provided i only can a lot of images from 1 in a vec or with X images obtain a vec with X images, i can't increase the number

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Statistical Invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) + Perceptron (or another classifier such SVM).
Statistical Invariants give abilities to calculate features which still constant under the translation, rotation, isotropic scaling. They are easy for understanding and don't require high computational cost.